Giving permission to access only a specific EC2 instance
I'm trying to create a permission policy to access only instances of a specific region, so I've created the below policy:
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": "ec2:*",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:REGION:ACCOUNT:instance/*"
        }
    ]
}

But if I try to run this command:
aws --profile PROFILE ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids INSTANCE

I get this error:

An error occurred (UnauthorizedOperation) when calling the DescribeInstances operation: You are not authorized to perform this operation. User: arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT:user/USERNAME is not authorized to perform: ec2:DescribeInstances because no identity-based policy allows the ec2:DescribeInstances action.

Just for testing I've also tried with this policy:
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": "ec2:*",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}

And this works fine, which means there's probably an issue with the Resource key however I've double-checked the ARN and it's correct as far as I can see.
Any idea what I am missing?

Presume this is because DescribeInstances does not act on any specific resource, hence your resource ARN would need to be * for this action.

Consider using a condition on aws:RequestedRegion in your policy to restrict the region.
